# Angular 5: guard forward retrieved data to next component/route

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular-router

In an angular 5 app, there is a route guard that check from an API if an object exists:

//guard.ts excerpt

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.clientService.get(next.params.id).switchMap( data => {
    return Observable.of(true);
  })
  .catch( err => Observable.of(false))

}
```

//route.ts excerpt

```
{ path: ':id', canActivate: [ ClientDetailGuard ], component: ClientDetail }
```

this works perfect, but I am wondering if is there a way to pass the data retrieved from my service to next the route/component (ClientDetail), so I won't need to call the service again this again.
I tried to add

```
next.data.client = data;
```

before the return of Observable(true) but in the component, the ActivatedRoute's data does not have this value set. 
Or should I use something like [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)?

I know I can achieve this using some state container or a shared service to store/retrieve data, but I wouldn't like to do this at this time, as long as the app is not complex.

Comment: Either make an injectable service where u can make a behavior subject to store/subscribe to your data. Or use the router route data if its simple data, etc. route link ‘details:/id’. Or parameters in url such as url/details?param1. The service is best practice so u can pass objects and arrays, etc.

Comment: I want to avoid use of a shared/injectable service. And the approach using url parameters do not work: the url already has the id parameter (example), but I need to pass complex data (the clientService, in this scenario, retrieves a 'big' json from an API). I have taken a look at the Resolve from @angular/router and it seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I could do this using a Resolver instead of a guard

//route.ts

```
{ path: ':id', resolve: { client: ClientDetailResolver }, component: ClientDetail }
```

//resolver.ts
    @Injectable()
    export class ClientDetailResolver implements Resolve {

```
  constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private router: Router, public location: Location) {

  }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.clientService.get(route.params.id)
    .catch( err => {
      //handle error
      const path = this.location.path();
      this.router.navigate(["error", err.status], { skipLocationChange: true })
      .then( () => {
        this.location.replaceState(path);
      });

      return Observable.empty();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under-estimating the power of services.  Services are the best way to save/store data or states between components.  You can set the data from any component, pull the data from any component.  You don't have to worry about putting data in for the next route, instead you go to the next route and subscribe to your data on ngOnInit and boom, got everything you need.  Here is an example of just how simple it really is.

Example of service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    alertData = new BehaviorSubject({
        type: '',
        message: '',
        timer: 0,
        showing: false
    });

    constructor() {}

    setAlertData(data: AlertModel) {
        this.alertData.next(data);
    }
}
```

Example of using service

```
this.subscription$.push(this._as.alertData.subscribe((data: AlertModel) => {
    this.alertData = data;
    if (data.showing) {
        this.alertIsShowing = true;
    }
    else {
        this.alertIsShowing = false;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not worried about using a shared service, and I know how to use it. I was just wondering if there was other way, and the Angular' Resolve is a good solution: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve